# how to run bat file from my oracle pl sql procedure

Tags: oracle, batch-file, plsql

Ive created a directory on my oracle database:
example:

```
CREATE DIRECTORY execdir AS 'ABXD/EFGH';
grant execute on directory execdir to public;
```

Now, my bat file is placed on network drive which is:

```
//ABXD/EFGH
```

note: ABXD is already mounted in oracle database

my bat filename is below:
sample.bat

bat file content:

```
@echo off
pushd //ABXD/EFGH
FOR /f %%i IN ('dir /o:-d /b') DO (set LAST=%%i)
ren %LAST% data_1.jpg
popd
```

Comment: Not a solution, but: in `pushd //ABXD/EFGH`, I'd change the `/` to `\ `, which is the Windows path separator...

Answer (score 5):

You could use `DBMS_SCHEDULER`. There's a nice explanation on [Oracle Technology Network](https://community.oracle.com/message/2067003#2067003) so - have a look.

Shortly: you can't run .BAT file directly; envoke CMD.EXE first, and let it run your .BAT file.

Excerpt from that page:

```
BEGIN
   DBMS_SCHEDULER.create_job ('myjob',
                              job_action            => 'C:\WINDOWS\SYSTEM32\CMD.EXE',
                              number_of_arguments   => 3,
                              job_type              => 'executable',
                              enabled               => FALSE);

   DBMS_SCHEDULER.set_job_argument_value ('myjob', 1, '/q');

   DBMS_SCHEDULER.set_job_argument_value ('myjob', 2, '/c');

   DBMS_SCHEDULER.set_job_argument_value ('myjob', 3, 'c:\temp\test.bat');

   DBMS_SCHEDULER.enable ('myjob');
END;
```