# Execute .bat file from a JOB in Oracle

Tags: oracle, batch-file, oracle11g

I am trying to create a JOB from Oracle 11g that runs a .bat file on my server.

The .bat file contains something simple

```
@echo off
echo Hello World
pause
The JOB is programmed as follows.
```

```
BEGIN
  DBMS_SCHEDULER.CREATE_JOB(
    job_name        => 'TEST_BAT',
    job_type        => 'EXECUTABLE',
    job_action      => 'host cmd /c D:\Report\TEST.bat',
    start_date      => SYSTIMESTAMP,
    repeat_interval => 'FREQ=DAILY; BYHOUR=12; BYMINUTE=0; BYSECOND=0',
    enabled         => TRUE
  );
END;
```

I also tried to do the JOB in the following way, but still the same error comes out

```
BEGIN
    SYS.DBMS_SCHEDULER.CREATE_JOB( job_name => 'TEST_BAT',
        job_type => 'EXECUTABLE',
        job_action => 'C:\WINDOWS\system32\cmd.exe',
        comments => 'Job to call batch script on Windows',
        auto_drop => FALSE,
        number_of_arguments => 1,
        enabled => FALSE);

    SYS.DBMS_SCHEDULER.SET_JOB_ARGUMENT_VALUE( job_name => 'TEST_BAT', argument_position => 1, argument_value => 'D:\Tests\Export\TEST.bat'); 
    SYS.DBMS_SCHEDULER.ENABLE( 'TEST_BAT' ); 

   END;
```

Run it with the SYS user, in case it was a permissions issue, but it still doesn't work.

This is the JOB log

> ORA-27370: job slave failed to launch a job of type EXECUTABLE
> ORA-27300: OS system dependent operation:accessing job scheduler
> service failed with status: 109
>  ORA-27301: OS failure message: The
> system cannot find the file specified.
>  ORA-27302: failure occurred
> at: sjsec 9
>  ORA-27303: additional information: The system cannot
> find the file specified.

I was expecting the .bat file to be executed on my server with the "Hello World"

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51359967/how-to-run-bat-file-from-my-oracle-pl-sql-procedure

Comment: and `host` is just a command of sqlplus